# Facebook SDK for Python - Get user email

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Prerequisite**

- My Facebook application have permissions to get user `email`
- I've checked that getting user `email` with Javascript is working fine
- Server has non-expired `access token` of user

---

**Goal**

- Now, I'd like to do same task on server side with [pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk)

---

**Problem**

- Succeed to get `name` and `id` of user, but `email` is not included
- I'd like to get `email` together

---

**Code**

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='CAA...DZD')

graph.get_object(id='me')
# result : {u'name': u'Username', u'id': u'123456789'}

graph.get_object(id='me?fields=email,id,name')
# Error : facebook.GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object('me')
args = {'fields' : 'id,name,email', }
profile = graph.get_object('me', **args)
```

Comment: Why is `'fields'` a tuple, i.e. the comma at the end?

Comment: you can remove the comma at the end.

Comment: @vienvu : i tried the same thing, instead of 'me', i used a user id. I am able to extract only id and name, nothing else. Any idea ??

Comment: @Nitin: Having the same issue.

Comment: email settings by the user can block access to email.